# hadoop wordcount example java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hdfs error

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I just installed Hadoop-2.2.0. I tried WordCount example from ">this link but I got this error. How can I fix that?

```
hadoop$ bin/hadoop hdfs -copyFromLocal in /in
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hdfs
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hdfs
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

**copyFromLocal**

**Usage:** `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal <localsrc> URI`

**Ex:** `hadoop$ bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal in /in`

Similar to put command, except that the source is restricted to a local file reference.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the command you are looking for is:

`hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal in /in`

Comment: I think you are right. It used to be
`hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal <localsrc> URI`, but it has changed in the new API. 

All the shell commands can be found here:  https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html